# How can i fill a matrix dynamically with strings in matlab?

Tags: string, matlab, matrix, matlab-uitable

I want to print a table via `uitable`, with the data for the table-entries stored in a matrix called `plot`. Every entry should be a string, consisting of 2 chars i.e. `p0` or `u1`,...
The matrix should be filled in two nested for-loops.

But whenever I want to store a string as an element. i.e. `plot(i,j)='a1'` i get the error

```
"??? Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts"
```

on the other hand, when i initialize a matrix completely at the beginning i.e.

```
plot=['aa' 'ab';'ba' 'bb']
```

it seems to work just fine.

I would be very thankful for any ideas concerning the problem.
Would there be any way to solve the problem with a cell array?

Answer (score 1):

To store string, use a cell array. Also, don't call  your matrix `plot`, that's the name of a built in function. For example:

```
plotData{1,2} = 'hello';
plotData{1,1} = 'hi';
```

To access an item in the cell array:

```
plotData{1,1}
ans = hi
```

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot! I thought, a Cell Array wouldn't work as 'Data' with an uitable, but it seems to works just fine :)